# Download Google Analytics information with a unique user ID

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm looking to download hit data from a Google Analytics view for a small period of time that includes unique ID for a session and URL that was viewed. I believe I could do this going forward by setting something in Google Tag Manager to a Custom Dimension, but I was looking to avoid that (we have a good number of custom dimensions) and because I wouldn't be able to go backward.

Is it possible in the free version of GA to do something like? I picture the output being the URLs in my x-axis and my users in the y-axix with counts.

I'll be looking to take this data and do a cluster analysis to determine user behavior types.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. Google Analytics does not expose a user specific id via the API or via data exports in a standard account (in GA360 you could use BigQuery to extract the client id).

You either have to set up a custom dimension (as you said this does not work for historic data), or try and use calcuated fields in Google Data Studio in the hope that if you aggregate enough different dimensions into one field you will end up with something specific per user.